# Useful resources to help understand go-ethereum source code

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I am new to ethereum community and I want to study the implementation of Ethereum (e.g. geth) and contribute to the  [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) project.

However, I find the source code hard to understand by only looking at the project source code. I have read the white paper and yellow paper of Ethereum, but these are still high-level ideas of Ethereum protocol and contain very little information of the structure and functionality of every module in go-ethereum project. Although the source code is accompanied by a bunch of comments, it is still difficult for beginners (like me) to understand.

So, are there any resources or reading materials that explain the module structure and implementation details of go-ethereum project?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow this link. It has explanation on various parts of Ethereum Source code in golang. (Transaction processing, networking, mining issues etc)

https://github.com/agiletechvn/go-ethereum-code-analysis

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chinese version of ETH tutorial: https://github.com/Billy1900/Ethereum-tutorial. And English version is also concluded in the repo.